# source code to store image into MySql database and retrieve it and display in Jsp using technologies servlet and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have the code to store image into database..that i have completed. But the problem is to  fetch image to my jsp page. Please help!

```
PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        MultipartRequest m = new MultipartRequest(request, "d:/workspace/zqa/WebContent/images");
        String name1=m.getParameter("name");
        String address=m.getParameter("address");
        String state=m.getParameter("state");
        String country=m.getParameter("country");
        System.out.print(name1+address+state+country);
        String p=m.getParameter("phone");
        int phone=Integer.parseInt(p);

  //      Blob b1=(Blob) m.getFile("filename_1");

    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    if (isMultipart) {
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        try {
            List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            }
        } catch (FileUploadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos); 
    byte[] personByteArray = baos.toByteArray(); 
    Details ds=new Details();
    ds.setName(name1);
    ds.setAddress(address);
    ds.setState(state);
    ds.setCountry(country);
    ds.setPhone(phone);
   Blob b = (Blob) Hibernate.createBlob(personByteArray); 
    ds.setImage(b);
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); 
    Session session =sessionFactory.openSession(); 
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction(); 
    session.save(ds); 
    tx.commit(); 
    pw.print("successsss");
```

Comment: `But the problem is to fetch image to my jsp page.` Where is code that fetches records???

Comment: sorry aniket....wait i will update...or else if u have some idea then pls tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a method on the server side which stream the image in the HttpServletResponse object. Here is an example with a file. You need to adapt with your method to retrieve the object. Since you didn't post your method to retrieve your image from the DB, it's all I can offer you as example.

```
public void streamImageContent(String name, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException {

    File file = fileService.getFile(name);

    try {
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(file), out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

And in your JSP something like

```
<img alt="Logo" src="<c:url value="[yourUrl]?name=[ImageName]")">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
  <%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
<%@ page import="java.util.zip.*"%>
 <%  
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://118.67.244.39:3306/xyz"; 

     ResultSet rs = null; 
     Connection connection = null;
     PreparedStatement psmnt = null; 

     InputStream sImage; 
       try { 

       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

       connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username","password"); 

         psmnt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT file_data FROM file WHERE id = ?"); 
         psmnt.setString(1, "11"); 
         rs = psmnt.executeQuery(); 
        if(rs.next()) { 
        byte[] bytearray = new byte[1048576]; 
        int size=0; 
        sImage = rs.getBinaryStream(1); 
         response.reset(); 
           response.setContentType("image/jpeg"); 
        while((size=sImage.read(bytearray))!= -1 ){ 
       response.getOutputStream().write(bytearray); 
     } 
       } 
     } 
      catch(Exception ex){ 
     out.println("error :"+ex); 
      } 
       finally { 

     //rs.close(); 
    psmnt.close(); 
     connection.close(); 
      } 
     %>
```